unable to download windows 11 updates and apps from the Microsoft store, but can still browse the internet on the web browser
I have a windows 11 machine and unable to download windows 11 updates and apps from the Microsoft store.
I called up the cable company and stated it is not router, but mostly likely a Microsoft issue.
I tried the following into CMD as an admin:
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /all
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
^ | | results when it I ran it
Windows IP Configuration
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 13:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 14:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
------------- This is where I stopped
netsh int ip set dns
netsh winsock reset
please advise

You don’t have an internet connection based off your information. I can absolutely guarantee you that it’s NOT a Microsoft issue. You need to have your ISP diagnose your issue.

Is that where YOU stopped the output, or did the output end there? If you stopped it, please re-run ipconfig /all and add the full output to your question. None of the connections you have shown have a connection. What is your network setup like? Are you connected directly to the ISP-provided modem/router using a cable or WiFi? Are there any other devices connected through this internet connection and are they working or not? Add this and other requested information directly to the question itself. As it is currently, there is not enough information to answer your question with certainty.

Are you browsing websites you've been to previously, or have you tried an internet search and gone to a site you have not been to before, and did it load or not?

----Ramhound. I called up the ISP and they stated everything was fine on their end.

---music2myyear. As for browsing websites, I was able to get to sites I never been to before and loaded just fine. And I am connected through the ISP provided modem/router using a cable
